# Generic ruby method implementation for fetching data from a hash of Nosql data

Tags: ruby

How do get a specific value from a hash of hash using a custom ruby implementation

I have a nosql data that comes out in this particular format:

```
{:bookname=>"The Fight for Guadalcanal", 
:sourceSystemId=>"d4ba4799-atil45-4a", 
:checkouttimestamp=>"2018-12-12T04:38:34.476796700Z",:firedevents=>[{:operation=>"GET", :entity=>"warbooks", :keys=>[{:name=>"book_guid", :value=>{:FieldString=>"e33almmatter-syslibrary"}}], 
 :attributes=>[{:libLocation=>"a44364", :value=>{:FieldInteger=>3994}}, {:name=>"big_response", :value=>{:FieldString=>"The Battle for Enderson Field, also"}}],
 :customizable=>true}]}
```

Is there in method in ruby providing the key as a argument parameter?

I know there is fetch method in ruby that gets me the value:

```
test.fetch(:firedevents,()).fetch(:operation))
```

this does get me the value GET

but the problem I have the number of arrays or hashes in the data-set that may vary upon each operation so I am in lookout for a method that gives me a value on passing key as argument.

e.g.: `ruby_mthod(sourceSystemId.to_sym)` should get me `d4ba4799-atil45-4a`

Comment: _"a method that gives me a value on passing key as argument"_ – well, that's exactly what [`fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) does: _Returns a value from the hash for the given key_. Seems like you want something else. Please clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch will be enough to get `sourceSystemId` (assuming your data is in `h`):

```
> h.fetch(:sourceSystemId)
# => "d4ba4799-atil45-4a"
```

If you're looking for something more generic, take a look at [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig). It lets you chain hash access in a neat way:

```
> h.fetch(:firedevents).first.fetch(:keys).first.dig(:value, :FieldString)
# => "e33almmatter-syslibrary"
```

EDIT:

As @Stefan suggested, `#dig` can be used for the whole operation:

```
> h.dig(:firedevents, 0, :keys, 0, :value, :FieldString)
# => "e33almmatter-syslibrary"
```

Comment: Or `h.dig(:firedevents, 0, :keys, 0, :value, :FieldString)`

Answer (score 0):

You can go recursively through the hash as:

```
def deep_find(key, object=self, found=nil)
    if object.respond_to?(:key?) && object.key?(key)
      return object[key]
    elsif object.is_a? Enumerable
      object.find { |*a| found = deep_find(key, a.last) }
      return found
    end
  end
```

or you can use [deep_find](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#deepfind) from hashie gem